# SQL Server sys.messages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database on one server for which I added some custom error messages into the sys.messages view using the sp_addmessage stored procedure.

I find that when I restore the database onto another server the sys.messages are not copied.
this is the first time i am using custom messages in the sys.messages view.

Where might I be going wrong?

Am I supposed to copy the custom error messages each time i restore the DB?

Or am I supposed to add the error messages in the master DB?

I am doing my own research but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up the custom error messages again either manually or from the original script

You can script them out of course

```
SELECT
   'EXEC sp_addmesssage ' + ...
FROM
   sys.messages
WHERE
   ...
```

Personally, this is why I don't use them: they become a maintenance overhead especially if you have different entries for different databases on the same server. I've had a 3rd party app use them and cause conflicts with another... ggrrrrr

Comment: Thanks a ton! These are a maintenance overhead but I don't have any other way to do what i need to do...